# Xepersian equivalant persian commands not working

Tags: xepersian

I am getting an error of "Undefined control sequence." while using equivalent Persian commands in xepersian. for example: \شروع

---

PS:I have downloaded the newest version of Mactex.

Answer (score 1):

According to [issue#16 on xepersian github](https://github.com/tex-xet/xepersian/issues/16):

You need to pass the option localise=on to the xepersian package; i.e.

```
\usepackage[localise=on]{xepersian}
```

Comment: How do commands that have a space between them work? Ex: متن سياه?

Comment: You should use half space